# nodejs ts manage shared variable

Tags: node.js, typescript, singleton

I have a singleton module

```
class Singleton {
    private static instance: Singleton;
    private _foo!: string;
    private constructor() {

    }
    static getInstance() {
        if (!Singleton.instance) {
            Singleton.instance = new Singleton();
            Singleton.instance._foo = "aaa";
        }
        return Singleton.instance;
    }
    get foo(): string {
        return this._foo;
    }
    set foo(txt) {
        this._foo = txt;
    }
}
export let global = Singleton.getInstance();
```

in the main file I do this

```
// main.ts
import { global } from "./global";
global.foo = "bbb";
console.log(global.foo);
import("./part1").then((t) => {
  t.default();
});
```

this outputs "bbb".  Now main module import another file (part1.ts)

In part1.ts I import again the global module

```
// part1.ts
import { global } from "./global";
export default () => {
  console.log("test:" + global.foo);
};
```

the output is "aaa", but I need to output previous setted value (bbb)
How can I make this?

Comment: *the output is "aaa", but I need to output previous setted value (bbb)* - there's no evidence it was previously setted. The question doesn't show how these modules are related. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 1):

Singleton classes can often be considered antipatterns, they are certainly antipatterns in modular environments. Modules naturally provide singletons in Node.js because they are evaluated only once under normal circumstances.

The problem with original code is that `global.foo = "bbb"` in main.js is evaluated after `console.log(global.foo)` in part1.js, so there is race condition.

It could be:

*global.js*

```
export default { foo: 'a' };
```

*part1.js*

```
import _global from "./global"; // _global.foo === 'a'
import "./part2";  // _global.foo === 'b'
console.log(_global.foo);
```

*part2.js*

```
import _global from "./global";
_global.foo = "b";
```

Another potential problem in original code is that `global` import shadows `global` global.

Comment: I can't import part1 before, the race condition must be exact like my example

Comment: Why? You don't show how where part1 is used in your example. It's not imported in main.

Comment: Is there a real reason why there should be dynamic `import()` and not static `import`?

Comment: Yes, because modules are loaded by folder scan

Comment: At this point the question doesn't contain the problem that could be replicated besides singleton class. There's no race condition. It should work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-covzy1